# How to display excel file data in the web page exactly as it is in the file in phpexcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel library in my codeigniter application. I have this code

```
$file = './assets/test.xlsx';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
$cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();
foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {
    $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
    $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
    $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();
    if ($row == 1) {
        $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
    } else {
        $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;
    }
}
```

It reads an excel file and stores the data of the file in an array. But how do I display the file's data in my page exactly as it is in the file. The table will be dynamic and all the data should be in the same order as in the file.

Comment: The arrays keep the order of inserted elements, you'd just have to output the content with a mix of table / td.

Comment: Use PHPExcel's HTML Writer to generate the markup, and it will even handle the styling for you